# width("1052"); not working?

Tags: jquery, css

does anyone know why the

```
$(".completeholder").width("1052");
```

Is not working in my [JS File?](http://www.nightlifebratislava.com/demos/resize/working/searchform.js)

When you click the 'Outside HTML" on [This Link](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/resize/working/), and then navigate to 'I want to custom search', that code I have shown above should execute when you press the first 'next button'. The width should change so that there is room for the new div I 'show' by clicking that next button.
The css file should be okay, as [it's over here](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/resize/working/style.css)

```
.completeholder {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 796px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Any Ideas? Thank you very much everyone :))

Comment: Use a number `(1052)` instead of a string.

Comment: No luck :/, but I appreciate your help mblase75 :)

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/qBkvz/ There must be an error elsewhere.

Comment: You have heaps of JS errors on your page. You might want to address those.

Comment: Well, it's not really heaps of JS errors, it's just one error that occurs heaps of times... @pufAmuf, chrome and safari both have built in JS error checkers (press F12), and for firefox, the best one is firebug

Comment: Thank you peirix, I will do that for sure :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 4 divs that are parents of the div with the id of complete holder that have specified widths of 796px.  You will need to change those widths as well.

"colorbox", "cboxContent", "cboxWrapper", "cboxLoadedContent".

I changed the width of those 4 divs and then it looks fine.

$("#colorbox").width(1052);
$("#cboxContent").width(1052);
$("#cboxWrapper").width(1052);
$("#cboxLoadedContent").width(1052);

Comment: Thanks Narnian! Currently the code looks like this   $(".completeholder").width('1052');
   $(".colorbox").width('1052');
   $(".cboxContent").width('1052');
   $(".cboxWrapper").width('1052');
   $(".cboxLoadedContent").width('1052'); and I still have no luck - it might also be those jquery errors that everyone is talking about

Comment: @pufAmuf When you get it working, you should add a common class to those so you can change them all in one go. Even without one, you might find it faster to write `$(".completeholder .colorbox .cboxContent .cboxWrapper .cboxLoadedContent").width(1052);`

Comment: You need to use $("#colorbox") instead of $(".colorbox").  For the completeholder div, you also have that as the class, but not for the other divs.

Answer (score 0):

According the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/width/) you can use a integer `$('').width(1052);` or if you use a string, you must add the unit `$('').width('1052px');`

Comment: Tha'ts not true. The documentation on that page says "When calling .width('value'), the value can be either a string (number and unit) or a number."

Comment: I tried all of those. I think the problem may be with the type of jquery version I'm using... I'll do more tests

Comment: Like you just copy, *...a string (number and unit)...* A string with number AND unit.